# Using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to prove that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I tried $$ \left | \frac{\tan x}{x}-1 \right | <1+\left | \frac{\sin x}{x} \right |\left | \frac{1}{\cos x} \right |<1+\frac{\delta^2}{2}\left | \frac{1}{\cos x} \right | $$

and I failed to deal with $\left | \frac{1}{\cos x} \right |$.

Is there an easier way, or something with this way ?

Comment: You've already given too much away with your inequality. How can you make this smaller than $\epsilon$ with that stubborn $1$ there? Try another factoring and remember $(\sin x)/x \to 1$

Answer (score 0):

Use $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: That's what I did! Simple.

Comment: Note that the Question is about using $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, aka the definition of limits, to prove the result.

Comment: You can express this result in terms of ϵ and δ-you can look at this as a detailed hint. Now you fill in the blanks.